# Cosine-similarity between columns in a Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nlp, cosine-similarity

I have data that looks like this...

```
+-----------+--------------------+
| searchterm|               title|
+-----------+--------------------+
|red ball   |A big red ball      |
|red ball   |A small blue ball   |
|...        |...                 |
+-----------+--------------------+
```

I'm trying to find the cosine similarity between the searchterm column and the title column in Scala.  I'm able to tokenize each column without issue, but most similarity implementations I have found online operate across rows and not across columns, i.e. they would compare 'a big red ball' with 'a small blue ball' rather than the cross column comparison I actually want.  Any ideas?  I'm very new to Scala, but this is how I would do it in Python.

```
def get_text_cosine_similarity(row):

  # Form TF-IDF matrix
  text_arr = row[['searchterm', 'title']].values
  tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
  tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(text_arr)

  # Get cosine similarity 'score', assuming keyword is at index 0
  similarity_scores = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[0], tfidf_matrix)

  return pd.Series(similarity_scores[0][1:])


df[['title_cs']] = df.apply(get_text_cosine_similarity, axis=1)
```

Using `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity` and `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer`

Answer (score 0):

You could transpose the matrix and then do the cosine similarity

Comment: I'm looking for a solution in Scala

Comment: I don't know scala but it seems like it is not that challenging to transpose the matrix

Comment: Yeah, transpose is not feasible in spark given size of the dataset.